# Why does making a join layer editable cause so many issues?

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-joins

I'm using QGIS.  When I do a join it creates new column values with a long title because of the prefix it adds from the join.  I need to shorten the column names in order to create new shapefiles from different selections from the attribute table.  I tried to re-do the join and make the join layer editable, as in the screen shot.  It completes the join, but every time I try to open the new attribute table it stalls and QGIS crashes.  What happened here?  [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you read this comment by @PolyGeo to an older post by you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380404/why-is-my-join-not-working#comment623325_380404
Please respect what this guideline.

Comment: a simpler answer is to use the `custom field name prefix` to set a shorter or empty prefix for the joined field names

Comment: @IanTurton I just tried this but QGIS freezes when I click on the field from the joined table in attributes form

Answer (score 1):

When you join the layers, by default, QGIS will prepend the layer name to the joined fields names. This means you will have multiple fields like `CensusACSBlockGroup_<joined field name 1>`, `CensusACSBlockGroup_<joined field name 2>` etc.

As the error says, field names of Shapefiles can be no longer than 10 characters. When the field names are automatically truncated (to 10 characters) they become only `CensusACSB`, and are no longer unique.

Either save in a format that allows longer field names (such as `GeoPackage`), or as @Ian Turton mentions in his comment, check the option for `Custom field name prefix` and either make it blank (field names will not be prefixed), or enter something very short like `j_` to signify it is a joined field.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This means the joined layer is not editable. First export it in an editable format (shapefile, geopackage).

Comment: I'm having this issue with an editable joined table

Comment: @Luffydude : Without more information, it's difficult to say what happened. Best post a new question with details and screenshots (and a reference to this post, if you want).